# Get Email Addresses From Exchange Given DirectoryEntry

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchange-server-2007

I'm looping through all the users in our AD environment, and reading their email address so I can update it in another system. I'm using the `System.DirectoryServices` library. Simplified example below. What I'm finding is that the `mail` attribute is not always correct and is often missing even though the user has a valid mailbox setup and functional in Exchange. So, the question is, given a `DirectoryEntry`, is there any way to list the user's primary email address (and ideally any aliases) from Exchange other than reading the `mail` attribute? I've seen some [examples that use the `proxyAddresses` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602854/c-sharp-list-all-email-addresses-in-ms-exchange), but these don't seem to be reliable either. I am looking for a solution that comes directly from Exchange. No if-and-or-buts about it. This is their email address.

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher("(&(mail=*))");
search.PageSize = 1000;
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
foreach( SearchResult result in search.FindAll() )
{
    DirectoryEntry entry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Properties["mail"].Value);
}
```

Comment: are you familiar with `PrincipalContext` you can get at ones email address on the domain that way as well.. also step thru the code and change this line `entry.Properties["mail"].Value` to the following `entry.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();`

Comment: @DJKRAZE that just reads the `mail` attribute.

Comment: have you tried using PrincipalContext to get a list of all users or at least try it with your username which would be your SamAccount name that you use to long in on the network.. and you will see that  it will return the email address look up examples on how to get all AD Users using PrincipalContext

Comment: @DJKRAZE, Dude, it's not a problem with the code. I can look in AD Users and Computers and see the attribute is blank. `PrincipalContext` will still only read the `mail` attribute. The bottom line is the `mail` attribute can not be relied upon. I need something that interacts with Exchange directly.

Comment: try this web service advice given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705951/get-users-exchange-server-and-email-address-in-net

Comment: Exchange doesn't have a separate data store for this data. It's stored in AD. If you collect the data via an Exchange API (EWS or PowerShell), you're ultimately getting the same data. The `proxyAddresses` attribute is the place to look in AD.

Comment: @BrianDesmond, after further investigating and testing. I have verified you are 100% correct. If you will post as an answer. I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange doesn't have a separate data store for this data. It's stored in AD. If you collect the data via an Exchange API (EWS or PowerShell), you're ultimately getting the same data. The `proxyAddresses` attribute is the place to look in AD.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275636)

it depends on what properties are set when the object is created and what type of object it is:

For mailboxes (objectClass=user) if any of proxyAddress, mail, or textEncodedOrAccess is set exchange will not set any if the values, if none are set exchange will set all of the values.

For Mail-Enabled Objects (objectClass=user & objectClass=contact) targetAddress is mandatory, and the same rules apply for the other three.

Comment: Almost no user objects in our environment have the `targetAddress` attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange holds the email and aliases.
loop through your AD and use Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll to find the user in exchange.  then do what you'd like with their email addresses and aliases :)

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple way to know which property is used in the AD for the active directory properties
though it is a bit manual work to do but after going through some samples you will come to know all the properties that being used to hold the email value

below, you can loop over the properties names for some user and try to notice which property holds the email value
after several tries with different users you will be able to know the different properties name that hold the email and used for getting the email from all over the AD

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ConnectionString, ProviderUserName, ProviderPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
 /******************************/

 DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
 search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + username + "))";
 search.CacheResults = false;

 SearchResultCollection allResults = search.FindAll();
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 foreach (SearchResult searchResult in allResults)
 {
     foreach (string propName in searchResult.Properties.PropertyNames)
     {
         ResultPropertyValueCollection valueCollection = searchResult.Properties[propName];
         foreach (Object propertyValue in valueCollection)
         {
             sb.AppendLine(string.Format("property:{0}, value{1}", propName, propertyValue));
         }
     }
 }

 return sb.ToString();
```

you can even use this to get some properties name that you can't find directly in the AD

Comment: Thanks, but this is not helpful. This is still reading properties from LDAP, which as I've tried to express is not accurate. I need something that communicates with the Exchange server directly.